# Yocto recipe set hostname on raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, recipe

How can I set a hostname with Yocto recipe for raspberry pi 4?
I'am trying to set up a personalized hostname and hosts files on yocto raspberry image but I don't know how to do it.
Here is my file's examples.
"hosts"

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ sudo vim hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       my_personalized_hostname
```

and hostname

```
hostname
```

Any helps? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`hostname_pn-base-files = "your_hostname"`
in a `.conf` file works for yocto releases before "honister".

With "honister" and later you need to use
`hostname:pn-base-files = "your_hostname"`

The override syntax was changed with "honister" (`:` instead `_` as override operator).
Chapter "Conditional Syntax (Overrides)" of the Bitbake manual has all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Set `hostname_pn-base-files = "your_hostname"` in local.conf.

Answer (score 0):

The `local.conf` entry doesn't do the trick, as suggested by the previous answer. The value is getting overridden somewhere else.

I found that the `oe-core/meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb` file in my layers directory contained a line like this:

```
hostname = "${MACHINE}"
```

When I changed `${MACHINE}` to the value of my choice, my environment was created with my desired hostname.